# Spring WebClient and client_credentials grant

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

My question is specific to **spring-security 5.1.0** and using the Spring WebClient. I am working in a server environment using Spring Boot 2.1.0. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=spring%20security%20client) may have been asked already but at the time was unable to be answered.

Reading through the spring-security [5.1.0 release notes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/), it appears they have added support for client_credentials auth flow, specifically adding it to a WebClient Bean so the end-user never has to worry about the auth token. I am attempting to do exactly this but the APIs/documentation have me completely lost. My current work is below...

```
private ClientRegistration clientRegistration() {
    return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("registration-id")
        .clientId("client-id")
        .clientSecret("secret")
        .tokenUri("token-url")
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
        .scope("scopes")
        .build();
}

@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository = new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.clientRegistration());
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService = new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
# These are unused ^ but pieces of documentation seem to indicate they are required

    return WebClient.builder()
        .filter(new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction()) # this requires 2 arguments that I do not have
        .build();
}
```

My end goal is to be able to Autowire the WebClient bean anywhere and simply make requests that have the *bearer* auth automatically added.

Answer (score 1):

As Spring Security 5.1 adds simpler implementation for OAuth2 authentication mecanism, I suggest you have a look to this more recent post : [StackOverflow - Spring Security 5.1 - Get token for client credentials flow with WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190850/spring-security-5-1-get-token-for-client-credentials-flow-with-webclient/53583676#53583676).

From now on, you do not need to manage any `ClientRegistration`. Everything can be set using properties.

Then, for WebClient instanciation, the `ClientRegistrationRepository`needs to be injected from Spring and you need to use a new instance of `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` as you have not attaching any user to your application process. This way, you'll have the two arguments the `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` requires.

I tried to put the scenario where an client app is requesting data from a resource server on OAuth2 secured endpoints using WebClient in a GitHUb repo : [GitHub - Spring Security OAuth2 Machine-To-Machine process](https://github.com/Brico87/spring-security-oauth2-m2m). The authentication mecanism is now really easier with Spring Security 5.1.

Please ask if you have any question. Hope this will help you !

Comment: I tried to do something similar to your application the github but with a spring boot web application that need to make remote  OAuth2 WebClient calls with client_credentails and never got it to work. Alway ended up getting "Invalid Authorization Grant Type (client_credentials)"  from the DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver :(

Comment: Do you have any GitHub repo with code that I can get a look on please ?

Comment: @FlorentGornes : I have a problem with the web client, it get an access token for each request before calling the resource server. have you already test that?