# Spring Security 5.1 - Get Token for Client Credentials Flow with WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am attempting to get a bearer token via a `webclient` with the following setup for an integration test of a secured resource server in a servlet application.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          idp:
            clientId: id
            clientSecret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            scope: read
        provider:
          idp:
            authorization-uri: myidp/authorization.oauth2
            token-uri: myidp/token.oauth2
            user-info-uri: myidp/userinfo.openid
            user-name-attribute: name
```

And beans,

```
    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
        // (optional) explicitly opt into using the oauth2Login to provide an access token implicitly
        // oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        // (optional) set a default ClientRegistration.registrationId
        // oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("client-registration-id");
        return WebClient.builder().apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration()).build();
    }
```

and autowiring the webclient to a test and calling it like so,

```
webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:" + port + "/web/it")
                .attributes(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId("idp")).retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

It is my assumption the exchange function would either get an access token if available, or do a call to get a new one from the IDP. However it will always fail as the `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` as the `HttpServletRequest` is null.

With the overall test looking like, this feeds into an autoconfiguration to configure some beans for an IDP provider.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = WebITApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("web-it")
class WebJwtIt {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    @Test
    void testIdpJwt() {

        String response = webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:" + port + "/web/it")
                .attributes(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId("ping")).retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class).block();
        assertThat(response).isEqualTo("pass");
    }

    @RestController
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ImportAutoConfiguration(IdpAutoConfiguration.class)
    static class WebITApplication implements IdpSecurityAdapter {

              @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
        // (optional) explicitly opt into using the oauth2Login to provide an access token implicitly
        // oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        // (optional) set a default ClientRegistration.registrationId
        // oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("client-registration-id");
        return WebClient.builder().apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration()).build();
    }
        public static void main(String args[]) {

            new SpringApplicationBuilder().profiles("web-it").build().run(WebITApplication.class, args);
        }

        @GetMapping
        public String secured() {
            return "secured";
        }

        @GetMapping("/web/it")
        public String securedOne() {
            return "pass";
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws IdpSecurityAdapterException {
            try {
                httpSecurity.oauth2Client();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IdpSecurityAdapterException("Failed to Configure Oauth2Client", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public IdpProvider getIdpProvider() {
            return IdpProvider.MyIdp;
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway for a webclient to get the token for me and add it to the request? I know this was possible with the `spring-security-oauth:OAuthRestTemplate` and reading the documentation I thought it was possible with a web client.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not instancing your WebClient the right way.

As you are on the *client side*, you do not have access to an `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`. This bean is supposed to be linked to a resource sever on which you log into using the `.oauth2Login()` method declaration on the `HttpSecurity`configuration. These details are explained here : [Spring Security 5 Oauth2 Login](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login).

Again, you are on the *client side* so what you need is an exchange filter function which will trigger a request to an authorization server to get a JWT token. You can use the `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` instead.

You better use a `WebClientCustomizer` to add the exchange filter function in the WebClient filter. Why ? Simply because injecting in your Spring application a `WebClient.Builder` will allow you accessing native metrics linked to web exchanges.

Hence, you will build your WebClient using a new instance of an `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` bean like this :

```
// Use injection to get an in-memory reposiroty or client registrations
@Bean
WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {

    // Provides support for an unauthenticated user such as an application
    ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            clientRegistrations, new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());

    // Build up a new WebClientCustomizer implementation to inject the oauth filter
    // function into the WebClient.Builder instance
    return new WebClientSecurityCustomizer(oauth);
}
```

As you are on the *client side*, you are not associating a user to your process, that's why you can not use any authorized client repository bean instanciation. Check on Spring Security documentation : [Spring Security documentation : Class UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/server/UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.html).

I tried to sum up a demo case in the following GitHub project : [GitHub - Spring Security OAuth2 Machine-To-Machine scenario](https://github.com/Brico87/spring-security-oauth2-m2m).

I hope this gives you more insights on WebClient configuration. Please ask if you have any question.

Comment: This is awesome, must have missed this response until now!

Comment: Just want to add for any readers if you're in a background thread/non-http thread in Servlet Environments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55308918/spring-security-5-calling-oauth2-secured-api-in-application-runner-results-in-il should clear that up too. With Spring Security 5.2 an appropriate configuration is available.

Comment: I have a problem with the web client, it get an access token for each request before calling the resource server. have you already test that?

Comment: Very nice explanation :)