# Spring Security 5 Calling OAuth2 Secured API in Application Runner results in IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

Given the following code, is it possible to call a Client Credentials secured API in an application runner?

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner test(
    WebClient.Builder builder,
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepo, 
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClient) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                var oauth2 =
                    new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                        clientRegistrationRepo,
                        authorizedClient);
                oauth2.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("test");
                var response = builder
                    .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
                    .build()
                    .get()
                    .uri("test")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .block();
                log.info("Response - {}", response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed to call test.", e);
            }
        };
    }
```

The code fails due to,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: request cannot be null
```

Full stack,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: request cannot be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.loadAuthorizedClient(HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.java:47) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.populateDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:364) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.lambda$null$2(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:209) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.attributes(DefaultWebClient.java:234) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.attributes(DefaultWebClient.java:153) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

With the failing method looking like,

```
public <T extends OAuth2AuthorizedClient> T loadAuthorizedClient(
    String clientRegistrationId,  Authentication principal, HttpServletRequest request){

    Assert.hasText(clientRegistrationId, "clientRegistrationId cannot be empty");
    Assert.notNull(request, "request cannot be null");
    return (OAuth2AuthorizedClient)this
        .getAuthorizedClients(request)
        .get(clientRegistrationId);
}
```

Which makes sense as there is not `HttpServletRequest` for it to use, its being called on start-up of the application.

Is there any workarounds other than make my own no-op `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`?

//Edit,

This is not a fully reactive stack. It is a Spring Web stack with the WebClient being used with in it.

I am well aware of the `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` which applies to a fully reactive stack and requires `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` and `ReactiveOauth2AuthorizedClient` which are not available due to this being in an application built on top of Servlet stack, not reactive.

Comment: what is your use case? can you provide more context

Comment: The "servletRequest cannot be null" was seems to be a result from not being in a Servlet Context. Using WebClient inside Controller or RestController works fine, but from a Component or Service you will get the exception. Scorpioo's answer below works great.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since I also stumbled across this problem I'll elaborate a bit on [Darren Forsythe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7554328/darren-forsythe) updated answer to make it easier for others to find:

The issue submitted by the OP resulted in an implementation of `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` that is capable of

> operating outside of a HttpServletRequest context, e.g. in a scheduled/background thread and/or in the service-tier

([from the official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.html))

Said implementation, the `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager`, is passed to the `ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` to replace the default one.

In my example this looks something like this:

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService)
{

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = 
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
            .clientCredentials()
            .build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = 
        new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, clientService);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
}

@Bean
WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager)
{
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 =
        new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            authorizedClientManager);
    oauth2.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("keycloak");
    return WebClient.builder().apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration()).build();
}
```

Comment: This works for me. So whenever you want to use @Scheduled on service which uses OAuth2 to call another rest service, you need to have custom OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.

Comment: This solution was kinda hard to spot for me at first. It looks much like the Spring Security Oauth2 Migration example but there is two important a differences. Note the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService`  in the first bean and creation of `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager`  in the second bean. Thank you Scorpioo590 this solved my overdue problem!

Comment: What spring security version is this? There's no such class OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager , i'm using 5.1.5

Comment: I am using the Spring Security Starter 2.2.2 which uses 5.2.1 of Spring Security

Comment: You saved my time sir, thank you for providing the solution :)

Comment: It is also an option to use the WebClient.Builder.defaultRequest(req -> req.attributes(clientRegistrationId("keycloak"))) instead of oauth2.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("keycloak");
As described here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21412#issuecomment-453472419

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I ended up asking this to the Spring Security team,</strike>

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6683

Unfortunately if you are on the servlet stack and calling to OAuth2 resources with pure Spring Security 5 APIs in a background thread there isn't a `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` available.

Realistically there's two options,

1. Implement a completely no-op version,

```
 var oauth2 = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepo,
                        new OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository() {
                            @Override
                            public <T extends OAuth2AuthorizedClient> T loadAuthorizedClient(String s,
                                    Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void saveAuthorizedClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClient oAuth2AuthorizedClient,
                                    Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void removeAuthorizedClient(String s, Authentication authentication,
                                    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

                            }
                        });
```

2. Implement a Servlet Version of `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`.  [UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository GitHub Source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/server/UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.java) which has some basic functionality than a pure no-op.

Providing feedback on the GitHub issue might help the Spring Security team to evaluate accepting a PR and maintaining a Servlet version of the `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`

I reached out the the Spring Security Team [Spring Security Issue 6683](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6683) and on the back of that a Servlet version of the `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` will be added in Spring Security 5.2 for usage on non-http threads.