# Spring GenericWebApplicationContext gets loaded despite web-application-type: NONE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

In My Spring 2.5 web application, I am trying to write a test in which I disable the fact that it's a web application : this is because the application also contains some scheduled task(s) that use some Oauth2 components to call other services.

These Oauth2 components behave differently depending on whether they are triggered from a Servlet context or not (see [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.html)).

Right now, when I execute my `@SpringBootTest`, I see that :

```
[org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext] [main] [629] [DEBUG] Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext
```

I would like to disable this, so in my application.yml, I set `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` , but it doesn't work I still see the WebApplicationContext (I also set the property to a wrong value, to make sure that was taken into account and failing : it was, so I know my applicaion.yml file is read and taken into account by me test).

My hope is that once I am able to disable this, then `ServletTestExecutionListener`
will not be triggered and no `MockServletContext` will be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we can't easily enable the auto-configurations we need that are disabled when we set webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE (see comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69970013/3067542 ), we have to take a different approach.

We can't easily prevent `ServletTestExecutionListener` to be called, but we can add our own TestExecutionListener that will reset the parts we need in the test context. Luckily, the listener we add gets called after `ServletTestExecutionListener` so can indeed "undo" what we need.

```java
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;

/**
 * It's difficult to test a scheduled task that is part of a web application : out of the box, Spring Boot will set up a mock servlet context
 * through {@link org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener}. But in production, the servlet context is null and HTTP calls through {@code WebClient} may fail
 * if it's not configured correctly - see <a href="https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.html">the doc</a>
 * for an example of how it should typically configured.
 * If not configured correctly, WebClient calls may fail at runtime, and we may not be able to reproduce easily in a test, because servletRequest is no tnull like in prod, but set to a mock servlet context.
 *
 * Using {@code ResettingServletContextToNullListener}, we reset to null the servletContext that was initialized in {@link org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener}, and create a context that is much closer to what it is at runtime in production
 */
public class ResettingServletContextToNullListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

  @Override
  public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) {
    System.out.println("resetting servletContext to null, like it is at runtime when a scheduled task is triggered..");
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(null);
  }

}
```

and then we can simply add this in our test :

```java
@SpringBootTest
@TestExecutionListeners(value = ResettingServletContextToNullListener.class, mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
class MyScheduledTaskIntegrationTest {

...

}
```

With that setup, the test context for the scheduled task is similar to what it is when it runs in production, ie servletRequest is null : we can then adjust our Oauth2 config so that it doesn't fail when it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

`@SpringBootTest` uses `WebEnvironment.MOCK` as the default configuration value for the `webEnvironment`.

If you don't want to test against a `WebApplicationContext`, you can override this value:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem when I do this is that some Oauth2 components that I need don't get loaded by Spring. My scheduled task will call some other services, and therefore expects an org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository to be injected. so now the application context loading fails. so I need that part of the WebEnvironment, but not the other one ;-/

Comment: If it's just a set of autoconfigurations that are missing (and you know which you need), you can add them manually to your test using `@Import(OAuth2AutoConfigration.class)` and customize the context to your needs.

Comment: OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration has @ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.SERVLET) . From what I can see, manually importing it doesn't bypass the conditional... I thought I would import the 2 configuration classes that OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration imports, but they are package private, so I can't import them directly. I tried an ugly hack by creating my own  OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration without the conditional, but in the same package ie org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet , but I am also stuck there

Comment: I see. What's the main reason to not run with a `WebApplicationContext`? If there's an auto-configuration you want to avoid, you could go the other way around and explicitly disable this configuration. If you want a _real_ `ServletContext` and not a mocked one, you can pick `RANDOM_PORT` for the `webEnvironment` and Spring Boot will start the embedded Tomcat.

Comment: that's not a port issue. I had asked the question a bit differently with different details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69885575/test-a-spring-boot-webclient-outside-of-a-httpservletrequest-context , but didn't get a response : when testing a scheduled task that is part of a webapp, the context that SpringBootTest sets up by default is not close enough to what it is at runtime, so the task fails in prod, but passes in tests. problem is that it's not an autoconfig that "screws" it, but ServletTestExecutionListener : if I can disable it, I believe I'll be fine